# Permanent of matrices of finite order

Tags: matrices, permanent

Assume $M$ is a $n \times n$-matrix with entries in $\mathbb{Z}$ such that $M^k$ is the identity matrix for some $k \geq 1$.

> Question 1: Is the permanent of $M$ non-zero?

This is tested for many random matrices and for example for $3 \times 3$-matrices with entries in $\{-1,0,1 \}$.

> Question 2: What is the largest absolute value the permanent can have for such $M$ with entries in $\{-1,0,1 \}$ for a fixed $n$?

Comment: If $M^k$ is the identity, then $\text{det}M=\pm1$, and the permanent is congruent to the determinant mod $2$, so is nonzero.

Comment: @JeremyRickard Nice solution. So even being invertible is enough. If you want you can post this as an answer to question 1.